# How to Drain Heat from a High Intensity Lightbox (2200 watt)?

Tags: microcontroller, heat, heatsink

As you may know, I'm working on designing a "lightbox" that will contain 3 high intensity metal halide bulbs - consuming a total of 1600 - 2200 watt. The purpose of the box is to generate ~40,000 lux of light in an area that's 24 inches by 24 inches.

The box is meant to open/close in 1 minute intervals. This will be accomplished through a series of "microcontrollers" and "servo" motors. The box will open from the front (the "door") and be lifted upward through the servo motor.

While the box is closed, no light will be emitted. While it is open, the goal is to cause as much light as possible to escape from the box. For this purpose, another series of "servo" motors will cause the bulbs to move forward slightly out of the box (closer to the subject).

The box will be built out of wood and the dimensions of the box will be about 18 inches, by 12 inches by 12 inches.

This is all background information. My main concern (and the reason for this post) is about "draining" the heat from the box so that the wood doesn't catch on fire.

Currently (based on several suggestions from SO members), I will be taking the following precautions:

1. I will be placing a 240 CFM fan UNDER the box to filter out the heat.

My question is about this is: How much can I expect the wood to heat up in 1 minute with such a fan present? 
Furthermore, I want to design the box so it can last for 15 and 30 minute open/close phases as well - how much more would

the wood heat up in 15/30 minutes compared to 1 minute?

If this would present a problem, would using a 400 CFM fan eliminate the problem? If not, would using 1 CFM fan on bottom (of 240 CFM) and another on top (of 100 or 240 CFM), help to enhance air flow and reduce heat  in the box?

2. To protect the wood from heat/fire I plan on spraying [No-Heat Spray](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003M8G39E). Will this help? Is it enough or are there other "coatings" I should apply?
3. I plan on coating the inside with a [mirror](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00725XBGG) like substance to project as much light as possible. Will this cause the wood to absorb more heat or less? (I assume less..)
4. Is there any other way to "fire proof" the wood (without converting it into metal which would cost $1,000 +) or perhaps my entire design is flawed?

Another question: Part of the plug from the bulb will be inside the box (around 8 inches) - will the heat damage the plug (which will be made from plastic I presume)?

As a side note, someone will be present whenever the bulbs are on so if there is a fire it will be seen. My primary goal is to avoid a fire in the first place but perhaps more importantly I want to avoid significant damage to the wood..

Comment: If the subject is a single point, i'd guess that making a good reflector  around your bulbs is more worth than a complicated mechanigal arrangement to move those hot bulbs outside the box.

(1.4 J/(g*K) ) * 0.5kg /2000 W - might be the correct formula to calculate how much 0.5kg of wood will heat up if you add 2kW to it - if I'm correct, it'll be 3K per second.

Comment: You might get an improved response if you accepted answers previously given on other questions you have raised on this subject. If the answers were not suitable then state why not.

Comment: @DThought - Subject is not a single point. And the wood is atleast 2 inches away from the bulb from all sides so I think formula is incorrect..

Comment: You apply 2000Watts of energy to a hollow container... The air inside + the wood outside will take all the energy.

Where do you think the energy will go to, if not heating air + wood?
What formula would you use?

Comment: Why won't it exit the box through the 240 CFM fan?

Comment: This seems more like a materials science and thermodynamics question than an electronics one.

Comment: Must the box be made of wood - this places major design constraints on it.  Unless the union the metal workers work for have swung an utterly amazing deal this need cost nowhere near 41000.  | You talk about 2200 Watt and 40,000 lux over a 24"x24" area - but lumen from bulbs and estimated light transfer would be useful. Note that halogen bulbs are ~= 100% efficient as 'light' sources - most of it is the IR (Infrared) range. Without in light-path filters a large % of the energy in will end up ON the target - is this intended. 2'x 2' =~ 0.4 m^2. If 50% of your IR out ends up on the target...

Comment: .. it will 'see' about 2000 * 50% /.4 = 2500 Watts/m^2 - ie several times full midday sun. Even at 20% transfer you get 1 sun ON the target. What is it? Does it care. | 40,000 lux on 0.4 m^2 = 16,000 lumen on target. At 2000W in that's 8 lumen/Watt. Your halogens will make maybe 2+ times that of "visible" light so you seem to be assuming about the same transfer % as I do above for IR. | Is there a reason NOT to use LEDS? You'd need about 100 to 150 W of LEDs and close to half of that would be light energy, leaving say 50-100W of cooling needed. Rather easier. LED cost is modest all considered.

Comment: 250 cfm air ~= 150 grams of air/second. Air is perhaps good for 2 J/gram/K so 150 grams gives 2000W/(150 grams x 2 J/gram) or only 6K rise for all energy input. So **IF** you can get the heat into the air then 250 cfm should be very adequate. [[[NBNBNB E&OE - that's out of my head and hopefully ~~ correct but needs checking for major assumption failures  :-) ]]].   | I'd use LEDs for this if at all possible. LED cost under $50 using cheap and cheerful and probably acceptable lifetime Asian sourced LEDs.

Comment: LEDS - [**This supplier has done OK by me so far**](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/group/LED-dot-matrix-digital-tube/812021_211532611/2.html) LEDS here 10W 20 30 50 W ... . eg [**$24 of these should be about right**](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Free-Shipping-10pcs-lot-10W-750-850LM-LED-Bulb-IC-SMD-Lamp-Light-White-High-Power/812021_697591892.html)  - unlike halogens you can get almost all of the light emitted "on target".

Comment: Is there any reason the lights have to remain on while the door is closed? Seems like turning them off shortly after closing the door and back on shortly before opening the door would avoid a lot of trouble ...

Comment: @brhans - the reason the lights need to remain on is because they require ~30 minutes before re-striking and they take several minutes to reach full illuminance - if we had turned them off/on this would defeat our goal of having it on/off in 1 minute intervals..

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Not sure where you got cost of $41,000. The cost for metal would be around $1500- $2000 and for wood around $200 - $300. Regarding estimated light transfer - I calculated that "subject" would receive between 27,000 lux and 35,000 lux (without mirrors, more if mirrors are used).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - about too much energy landing on target - did not think of this, good point. FYI, the "target" is a person. Would this burn him up? I hope not..

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - about the LED lights - how much lumens does a 10 watt LED light  emit? To be honest, I was trying to avoid LED lights as a source of light because the "target" does not feel comfortable looking at such light..

Comment: @MichaelMorl (1) $ = shifted_4_key and editing unallowed after a few minutes :-). (2) Cheap LEDS provide 60-100 l/W. Available off the shelf LEDS (Cree, Nichia, Osram, Lumileds, ... ) can make 120-150 l/w and you can get 150-180 - more for more $. Chinese LEDs I gave links to show claimed lumen and ones I specified give desired flux in $25-$50 range). (3) 40,000 lux is immensely immensely immensely bright. 1 sun is 100,000 lux so 40% full sun - and that's visible light with IR as extra. I suggest that a simple personal test with a large Wattage halogen lamp at 24" is in order.

Comment: @MichaelMorl What is the application? With luck your calculations may be "off". | Propelry done LED and halogten lighting should all be indistinguishable to all but nitpicking experts.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon  - yes I understand 40,000 lux is very bright.. this is the entire purpose of the experiment.. I know the sun can shine 50,000 - 150,000 (on a very, very bright day) too.. But the point about IR you made I did not consider.. At a practical level, is this dangerous? Subject (human) is about 20 inches from the source..

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - I think calculation is pretty accurate as I did a few tests (with several hundred watt) using a lux meter.. About LED lights - I don't know I guess I'm an expert because it gives me headaches :) However, it's possible the one I used was not "properly" done - I don't know.. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelMorl Light quality is very subjective. As I said - properly done. It is unlikely that you know what the "IT" is that gives you headaches, and you'd need at least single blind studies (very apposite term here :-)), to be sure re causation. LED lighting can have perceptible flicker and a few narrow emission frequencies. OR can be rock steady, and spectrally better than many other sources you'll meet. | As we do not know if you are trying to measure Octarine or the mass of Pi it's hard to know how anything meets your needs.

Comment: Some years ago I arranged an array of solar lights in an arc near an array of halogen lamps to simulate solar heating. Temperatures of 50 60 70 C were produced. Most users would blanch at this (or just burst into flames :-) ). A few simple tests are in order.

Comment: How many watt did you use in this experiment ?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - is there any way to reduce the heat between source and subject without infringing on the amount of light (in visible spectrum) that reaches subject?

Comment: One method is to focus it through an object of high transparency and conductivity which is cooled by 'magic" (maybe heat pipes or liquid cooling or ...). This is done, but I do not know what the magic material is. | You can also get materials which have optical cutoff frequencies and act like low/high pass filters. In fact, most "transparent" materials act this way - it's a matter of finding one with a cutoff that suits you. You can build multi layer interference filters but I suspect cost is high.

Comment: This must be an extremely well addressed problem by now - the eg theatre lighting people must deal with this. | Again, as your application is essentially 'secret' (point a bright light at someone up close) our ability to be creative is limited. | So far I've heard nothing that suggests LEDs are not a very good solution to consider.

Comment: Without using any heat filters will the subject get burnt? Is that what you are suggesting? When you arranged the solar lights that produced 70 C how close was the subject to the source?